# Pyodbc connection error but isql works

Tags: python, pyodbc, unixodbc

I've been round and round on this for hours.  I can't connect to a database via pyodbc, but I can use both tsql and isql to connect.

I'm now simply trying (which is probably wrong, but illustrates my point):

```
import pyodbc

pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={dev};SERVER=epdbdev01;DATABASE=something;USER=epnet2;OPTION=3;")
```

and I get this:

```
Error: ('00000', '[00000] [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen({dev}, 6): image not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I can connect via isql just fine, and for fun:

```
$ isql -v dev_fail user pass
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

$ isql -v dev user pass
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

you can see that if I use an invalid DSN I can an error, and with the correct DSN I'm in.  Now, the error for the incorrect DSN is the same error that I get with pyodbc, so seems something is crossed up.

I struggling with this I've resintalled things a few times and right now my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini are sym linked from my homebrew installs to my home dir as below:

```
.freetds.conf -> /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/etc/freetds.conf
.odbc.ini -> /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2/etc/odbc.ini
.odbcinst.ini -> /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

and finally, my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files:

**odbc.ini**

```
[dev]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = please work
ServerName = epdbdev01
UID = user
PWD = pass
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/lib/libtdsodbc.so
client charset = utf-8
```

Does pyodbc look for the driver information somewhere that I'm just missing?  I'm in the weeds on this one and I've probably crossed something up, but if isql works I would imagine that pyodbc would piggyback on that same connection information, but apparently now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I put the `odbc.ini` and the `odbcinst.ini` at `/etc`.  In addition, I reinstalled `freetds` from `homebrew` with the `--with-unixodbc` command and it worked.  Reading this [blog by JD Long](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2013/01/installing-debugging-odbc-on-mac-os-x/) for the 5th time helped me get the `iODBC` vs `unixODBC` disconnect.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/36939, "options were removed but the --with-unixodbc option is enabled by default now"